# Does entry to DynamoDB depends on the model class of you application?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a model class which has four member variables like this:

```
A.java
1.Attribute-1
2.Attribute-2
3.Attribute-3
4.Attribute-4
```

Now I make entries to the DynamoDB and the entries go successful and I can see the entries going.

Now I make few changes in the model and add 2 more attributes.

```
5.Attribute-5
6.Attribute-6
```

And in the application I am setting the values of these 2 attributes there.
Now when I try to insert some entry into the application then I am getting this error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

What is the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `DynamoDBMapper` class in AWS SDK JAVA with `save()` method.

1) Firstly, yes, you need to set the key values in the model object when you perform the update on existing item. `save()` performs either **create or update** the item

2) Secondly, save method has a **save behavior config**. You need to set the behavior accordingly based on your use case

> **public  void save(T object,**
>                        **DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression,**
>                        **DynamoDBMapperConfig config)**
>
> UPDATE (default) : UPDATE will not affect unmodeled attributes on a
>   save operation and a null value for the modeled attribute will remove
>   it from that item in DynamoDB. Because of the limitation of updateItem
>   request, the implementation of UPDATE will send a putItem request when
>   a key-only object is being saved, and it will send another updateItem
>   request if the given key(s) already exists in the table.
>
> UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES : Similar to UPDATE except that it ignores
>   any null value attribute(s) and will NOT remove them from that item in
>   DynamoDB. It also guarantees to send only one single updateItem
>   request, no matter the object is key-only or not.
>
> CLOBBER : CLOBBER
>   will clear and replace all attributes, included unmodeled ones,
>   (delete and recreate) on save. Versioned field constraints will also
>   be disregarded. Any options specified in the saveExpression parameter
>   will be overlaid on any constraints due to versioned attributes.

[Reference link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html)

**Sample Code:-**

```
Movies movies = new Movies();
//setting the partition and sort key
movies.setYearKey(1999);
movies.setTitle("MyMovie BOOL");

//New attribute added
movies.setProducts(Stream.of("prod1").collect(Collectors.toSet()));


DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

//Set the save behavior, so that it wouldn't impact the existing attributes. Refer the full definition above
dynamoDBMapper.save(movies,  SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES.config());
```